# Angular 2+ return variable or map from http request

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript

I have a service in which it either stores an object so I can access it in other components or requests data from a web api and returns it in a map.

**Example get for the objectService**

```
get(): any {
    if (this.object == undefined || this.object == null) {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/companies/get)
            .map((data: any) => {
                this.object = data;
                return this.object;
            });
    } else {
        return this.object;
    }
}
```

**Using the service to set page title**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.objectService.get().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.title.setTitle(data.name);
    });
}
```

So this works when I first load the page, but upon navigating to the page without a reload I get the following error `...subscribe is not a function`.  Which makes sense since I am returning an object and not an http request.

So I tried to return just the object and not a http request.

**Example get for the objectService**

```
get(): any {
    if (this.object == undefined || this.object == null) {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/companies/get)
            .map((data: any) => {
                this.object = data;
            });
    }
    return this.object;
}
```

**Using the service to set page title**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.title.setTitle(this.objectService.get().name);
}
```

This now flips the issue where page refresh gives me an error saying this.objectService.get().name is undefined and when I navigate to my component without a page refresh it works just fine.

Any help on trying to get this to work would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: convert the normal object to an observable by `Observable.of('this.object')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are mixing the observable and normal object!

I would say stick to the first aproach but while returning just the object, convert it to an observable so that it will work in your `onNgInit`

So your service will

```
get(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.object == undefined || this.object == null) {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/companies/get)
            .map((data: any) => {
                this.object = data;
                return this.object;
            });
    } else {
        return Observable.of(this.object);
    }
}
```

And your consumption will be still the normal and work for both the cases.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.objectService.get().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {  // this for response data
        this.title.setTitle(data.name);
      },
      (error: any) => {  // this for error
        console.log('error: %o', error);
      },
   );
}
```

Comment: Lets say the http request returns 404.  How would I detect this in my ngOnInit function?

Comment: Nvm figured it out, I set a `catch` after the `map` in the service and I am able to return the error and check for it when I consume the service.

Comment: you can also do it in component end by passing the second function to subscribe.